# Sending a bundle to other process

Tags: android, bundle, serializable

I am using the following code to serialize an object and to attach it to a bundle via putSerializable, then sending the bundle to other process via a Message. The problem is that I get an error that the object is not serializable. i tried adding "implements Serialazable" but I still get the same error.

```
public static byte[] serializeObject(Object o)
{ 
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 

    try { 
      ObjectOutput out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos); 
      out.writeObject(o); 
      out.close(); 

      // Get the bytes of the serialized object 
      byte[] buf = bos.toByteArray(); 

      return buf; 
    } catch(IOException ioe) { 
      Log.e("serializeObject", "error", ioe); 

      return null; 
    } 
  }
```

This is the code that make the call:

```
                ArrayList<byte[]> blist=null;
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                if (TriggerList != null && TriggerList.size() > 0)
                {
                    Iterator iter = TriggerList.iterator(); 
                    while (iter.hasNext()) 
                    {
                        Bundle entry = (Bundle) iter.next();
                        if (msg.arg1 == entry.getInt(ProjDefs.APP_ID))
                        {
                            if (blist == null)
                                blist=new ArrayList<byte[]>();
                            SerBundle sb = new SerBundle(entry);
                            byte[] bb = serializeObject(sb);
                            blist.add(bb);
                        }    
                    }
                    b.putSerializable(ProjDefs.SERIAL_DATA, blist);
                }
                NotifyClient(msg.arg1, ProjDefs.GET_APP_TRIGGERS_RESPONSE, 0, 0, b, null);
```

The serializable class:

public class SerBundle implements Serializable{

```
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public Bundle bundle;

public SerBundle(Bundle bundle)
{
    this.bundle = bundle;
}
```

}

Comment: @Simon : can u edit your post with code where u are preparing bundle and implements Serialazable

Comment: added the code that make the calls

Comment: are u sure implements Serialazable in your class

Comment: The serializable class adde to the question. note the first line, "extends serializable"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `Bundle` is already `Parcelable`. You can put a `Bundle` as a value inside of another `Bundle`, without having to mess around with `ObjectOutputStream`.

Comment: Can I also put an ArrayList of budles?